# Is there a way to scan a directory to see how many files of certain type there is?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, operating-system

So if I have a directory like below is there a way to scan how many files with a specific code in its name. For example if I want the number of files that start with 17042020 which would be 6 from the directory below?

```
1704202001-01.csv
1704202001-02.csv
1704202002-01.csv
1704202002-02.csv
1704202003-01.csv
1704202003-02.csv
001.png
002.pdf
003.docx
004.jpg
```

Comment: look at `os.walk`

Comment: Check the answer! - @15002941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module or just plain [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) :

```
 from pathlib import Path
 folder = Path(dir_of_files)
 specific_files = list(folder.glob('1704202001-*.csv')
 #or : list(folder.rglob('1704202001-*.csv') ... this will recursively search thru every subfolder for files that match this

 print(specific_files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use os to get a list with your files :

```py
import os
list = os.listdir("path")
for element in list:
     if yourconditions:
          print(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pathlib` module which is now best for paths

```py
import pathlib
from typing import List

"""!
@brief Finds files with the given unique code in name in directory
@param[in] directory pathlib.Path directory of searching
@param[in] unique_code str code in the filename
@return List[pathlib.Path] list of filepaths with unique code in name
"""
def find_files(directory:pathlib.Path, unique_code:str) -> List[pathlib.Path]:
    result:List[pathlib.path] = list()
    for filepath in directory.glob('*'):
        if filepath.is_file() and unique_code in filepath.name:
            result.append(filepath)
    return result

# Set Your directory!
directory:pathlib.Path = pathlib.Path('your/dir')

unique_code:str = '17042020'

found_files:List[pathlib.Path] = find_files(directory, unique_code)

print(f"Found files with unique code [{unique_code}]: {len(found_files)}")
for filepath in found_files:
        print(f"    {filepath.resolve()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

On Unix/Linux/macOS (so with your OS), **you can do it many ways in shell**.

Assuming you are in the specified folder, you can do for example:

```
ls | grep "1704202001" | wc | awk '{print $1}'
```

`ls` will list your folder files/subfolders
`grep` will filter your search with only lines containing your pattern
`wc` will count numbers of lines/characters of the search
`awk` will be told to print only the first column (wc will answer 3 numbers, only the first one is interesting for us)

If you want some **recursive search**, you can use `find`

```
find . -name "*1704202001*" | wc | awk '{print $1}'
```

`find` will perform a search in `.` and all the subfolders for the RegExp pattern (so we use the wildcard `*` to match the pattern in a complete file name).

Last but not list, **you may want to count how many files are containing your pattern** (not in the name, but inside the file himself). You can do it using `grep`:

```
grep -R "1704202001" | wc | awk '{print $1}'
```

You were asking for Python but also **operating-system help**, this answer is for the last :)

Hope it will helps some of you.