# Can you scan a directory for a file name to discover what type of file it is?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, operating-system

If I have a director like below:

```
1404202001-01.txt
1404202001-02.csv
```

Is there a way to first scan the directory for the name 1404202001-01 to then discover if its a text file or a csv file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to scan a directory to see how many files of certain type there is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271956/is-there-a-way-to-scan-a-directory-to-see-how-many-files-of-certain-type-there-i)

Comment: What's wrong with `endswith()`?

Comment: u can filter for the file u want using the ```glob``` module or  ```pathlib```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `pathlib`:

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = "1404202001-01"

for path in Path('.').iterdir():
    if path.is_file() and path.stem == filename:
        print(f"{filename} is a {path.suffix} file")
```

Output:

```
1404202001-01 is a .txt file
```

- [`pathlib.Path.iterdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir) lists all files in a directory. Used current working directory `.` as an example.
- [`pathlib.PurePath.stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) gets filename from path object.
- [`pathlib.PurePath.suffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix) gets extension from path object.
- [`pathlib.Path.is_file`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_file) checks if path object is a file.

I find using `pathlib` much easier than the `os` and `os.path` equivalent path functions. The naming of functions are quite different, but definitely much cleaner. Its also apart of [The Python Standard Library](http://ttps://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html#the-python-standard-library), so no installing required.

Answer (score 0):

Use os to get a list of files present:

```py
import os
list = os.listdir("path")
print(list)
```

Then with os you have :

- fileExtension
- basename

I won't do the full code, get a bit of documentation about those 2 functions and os library and it should be easy ;)